# How to find "public static void main" or the start of a program?

Tags: java, eclipse, search

I am working on an open source project, about 10Kloc, and I would like to know where the program starts. Naturally, I think I should search for "public static void main". I am using Eclipse. Does anyone know how to find this?

I tried using the search function in Eclipse, but it is not finding a match. Is my search configuration incorrect, or is there a better way to do find this method?

Any other suggestions for finding the start of a program are also welcome.

EDIT: This is an Eclipse plug-in, running with the Eclipse PDE.

Comment: You used file search?

Comment: Is it a web `Java EE` application?

Comment: You need to provide more information on the TYPE of application you are using before anyone can answer this for you.

Comment: @Reimeus, how can I find "main" used for the Run Configurations? I selected Run > Run Configurations, clicked a run configuration, but none of the tabs (Test, Main, ... Common) display an option to select a Main Type. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, I used file search, but found several main methods. I would like to know which main is associated with which run configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not all programs start with a main method. If its a Java EE app its usually some services, it is an Eclipse plugin, well then the starting point can be just about anywhere.

If you have done a search for "main" and found nothing, you probaly should start debugging. Put breakpoints in the beginning of every method that looks like it might be a likely startpoint.

Breakpoints in all the constructors are a good idea, since the program will most likely start by instantiating some classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming your project compiles):

1. Right click on the top node of your application (in package explorer)
2. Select run as -> Java Application
3. Eclipse should now present you with a dialog 'Select Java Application'

If it doesn't show you anyting in that dialog I'm afraid there isn't a class with a main.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the main method throughout your entire project:

1. Search->File (in Eclipse's menu bar)
2. Type in "public static void main(String[]" into the "Containing text" box.
3. Make sure your scope is set to workspace
4. Hit search.

The results will come up in the "Search" view. One of them is bound to be the one you're looking for.